# Copy and paste SDK from pc1 to pc2

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I've copied and pasted the SDK from **pc1** to **pc2**, however in **pc2** when I want to create a virtual device, the AVD manager tells that I have to download a system image again in order to create the emulator. So please any idea **how can I use the system images that I have already downloaded** in the copied SDK?

[image]

Comment: Make sure the folder you just copied everything into matches the project's SDK location. You can check this under the SDK Manager.

Comment: Yes, I have already done that, I mean I placed the copied SDK in a specific location in pc2 and import it from the SDK Manager in the android studio.